# vue v-if no css+js control

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuejs2

Tables hidden by the `v-if` directive, except for tables visible when loading the page for the first time, cannot be 'css+js' controlled.  If I delete all the 'v-if, everything works. Maybe it seems that only the first 0 of the for statement is executed.

What could be the problem?

This is the HTML code-

```
<div class="machine_w state" id="ss0">기기 상태</div>
<div class="machine_w time table" id="t0">압력 센서 상태</div>
<div class="machine_w total_user_time" id="a0">알람 상태</div>
```

This is the script code-

```
  methods: {
    vacuum_status() {
      for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        if (this.$store.state.mqtt_data_arr[i].vacuum_status == 1) {
          document.getElementById(`t${i}`).style.backgroundColor = "#e96666";
          alert(
            `${this.$store.state.mqtt_data_arr[i].device_name}호기 압력센서 비정상`
          );
          return;
        } else if (this.$store.state.mqtt_data_arr[i].vacuum_status == 0) {
          document.getElementById(`t${i}`).style.backgroundColor = "#3baf4a";
        }
      }
    },
}
```

Comment: The question should be updated to include the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem.

Comment: your working with vue you don't really need `document.getElementById` you can toggle a class or set styles when you loop over mqtt_data_arr, i.e `:style="item.vacuum_status ? '#e96666' : '#e96666'"` if you show more of the template including the loop should get a better answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the element that is not rendered by v-if, does not exist on the page.
It means there is no any selector.